# How to handle flags smartly to avoid warning "This expression always evaluates to true"

Tags: java, algorithm, flags

I can´t understand why the following method is giving me a warning in java eclipse, I agree it looks kind of silly but cannot figure a way of handling it smartly.

Especifically I am getting the following suggestion:

> "Remove this expression which always evaluates to true"

referring to the `flag` variable, and inside the `else` block I am getting

> "Remove this useless assignment to local variable `flag`"

```
boolean flag = true;
int counter = 1;
while(flag){
    // do something
    if(condition){
        counter ++;
    }else{
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the flag if it is always set to true?

Comment: At the moment the flag will be false and **could** be used to stop the loop, you use `break` to stop it before, so `while(true)` directly and keep the `break` only **OR** just remove the `break` chose one solution

Comment: It seems to me that `condition` is always true and never updated.

Comment: Well... You're not showing us the code for `condition`, so ...

Comment: my idea is to do "something" until the condition is false, then end the loop, the "condition" is another method

Comment: Apparently Java has decided that's not the case.  But if you genuinely believe that the code works as it should, then just simply ignore the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your loop like this:

```
// some code that sets condition initially goes here.
while(condition)
{
    counter++;
    // some code that updates condition goes here.
}
```

This should satisfy Java, and it has the nice side-effect of simplifying your code.  This is the canonical form of a `while` loop in Java, so unless you have a very good reason, you should not write it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that `flag` is useful if it changes and becomes `false`, if it never changes or is never used, it becomes useless. As you also use the `break` instruction, the loop will stop without using `flag` after being false, so yo may choose `flag` or `break`

```
int counter = 1;
while(true){
    // do something
    if(condition){
        counter ++;
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
```

or

```
boolean flag = true;
int counter = 1;
while(flag){
    // do something
    if(condition){
        counter ++;
    }else{
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

---

### Improvement

Also I'd suggest a high limit, to avoid an infinite loop **even** if you're 100% sure your `condition` will be false at a moment, that's a safety that costs nothing. Also, from the info you give it seems you could use `condition` directly as the while loop condition, using the `do/while` variant

```
int counter = 1, limit = 1000000;
do{
    // do something
    counter ++;
}while(condition && counter < limit);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your suggested improvement is an improvement (I mean no offense). About the limit: what if a wrong counter value will lead to some bugs further down the program? What if the program just needed another 1000 or so iterations to finish anyway? This may be a legitimate approach in certain scenarios, but I don't see a reason to do so here. And just my personal opinion, but I find `do while` really ugly and imo it shouldn't be used unless really necessary, which I think isn't the case here.

Comment: I agree there should be a limit I havent considered that scenario, i marked this as the answer as it gave me some useful information nobody else provided, thanks, 
for now I just removed the "break" and the warning is gone, but its good to know all these approaches

Comment: @Beko if the programm needs 1000 run only, itll stop at 1000, the 1000000 is to force stop on case you reach, and in fact it just a suggestion

Comment: I meant another 1k on top of the limit, just as an example. Anyway, I know you meant it as a suggestion. The reason I commented on it is because personally I thought both points were worsening rather than improving the code. Just IMO, and no hate, like I said. Probably not the right place to discuss this anyway. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

While you haven't stated what `condition` is, it appears to me that your while loop could simply be rewritten as `while (condition)`, without using a flag at all.

The warning appears because, as it states, `flag` is not being used in any meaningful way. This is usually a sign that you don't need it at all, as others have pointed out -- and if you do for some other reason you haven't given, then you need to reconsider how you're structuring this code.